# Is every ring of sets the power set of some set?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

It's clearly the case that $\mathcal{P}(V)$ is a ring of sets, but is it true that for any ring $\mathscr{R}$ there exists a set $V$ s.t. $\mathscr{R}=\mathcal{P}(V)$ ? What is $\mathscr{R}$ if a  σ-ring?

Comment: No, consider $\mathfrak R=\{A\}$, where $A$ is some non-empty set. $\mathfrak R$ is a $\sigma-$ring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, $\sigma$-rings of sets can look *extremely* different from powerset rings. Specifically, let's say two $\sigma$-rings $\mathfrak{R}_1,\mathfrak{R}_2$ are *similar* if they are isomorphic as partial orderings: that is, if there is some function $f:\mathfrak{R}_1\rightarrow\mathfrak{R}_2$ such that $f$ is a bijection and for all $A,B\in\mathfrak{R}_1$ we have $A\subseteq B\iff f(A)\subseteq f(B)$. For example, if $X,Y$ are any nonempty sets, the "trivial" $\sigma$-rings $\{\emptyset, X\}$ and $\{\emptyset, Y\}$ are similar in this sense even though $X$ and $Y$ might be very different (e.g. $X$ finite and $Y$ uncountable.)

It turns out that we can whip up $\sigma$-rings which aren't even **equivalent** to any powerset ring. Here are some examples:

- The cardinality of a finite powerset is always a power of $2$. So for example any finite $\sigma$-ring with an odd number of elements cannot be equivalent to a powerset ring (and note that every finite ring of sets is a $\sigma$-ring).
- For a more interesting example, fix an uncountable set $X$ and let $\mathfrak{U}$ be the ring of subsets of $X$ which are either countable or have countable complement. This is a $\sigma$-ring (this is a good exercise), but it's not a powerset ring. This is because in any infinite powerset ring there will be some element $x$ (in fact, many such elements) such that the set of minimal nonzero elements of the powerset ring which are contained in $x$ has the same cardinality of the set of minimal nonzero elements of the powerset ring which are not contained in $x$ (basically just let $x$ be "half" of the underlying set), but that fails for $\mathfrak{U}$.

Comment: I think I'm a little confused about the empty set. For any collection of sets, is the empty set a member? Also is $\mathcal{P}(\{X\}) = \{X, \emptyset \}$?

Comment: @Ethan No, the emptyset is a *subset* of every set but not a *member* of every set. Meanwhile, $\mathcal{P}(\{X\})$ does indeed have only two elements, but they are $\emptyset$ and $\{X\}$, not $\emptyset$ and $X$.

Comment: @Ethan I think I see the source of. the confusion - there are two notions of "ring" of sets, one requiring closure under complements and the other not. I was assuming the second, but maybe you were using the first; does my edit help clarify things?

Comment: I was basing on the definition I learned of closure under union and and closure under set difference, i.e. if A and B are in the ring then A\B is in the ring. Is that what you mean by close under complements?

Comment: @Ethan Yes, that's right.